Is the statement “I listen to music on my phone” about the location of the music files or about the device that is used to listen to the music?
When a person says “I listen to music on my phone”, do they mean that they listen to music that is stored on their phone or that they use their phone to listen to music, whatever its source is? Is the statement about location, device or both? Can you say that you listen to music on your phone if you only use streaming services to listen to music, i.e. the phone doesn't store the tracks?

I can see you can listen to music stored on your phone using a bluetooth headset for example.

They could mean both or either.  But The first inclination would be to assume that the phone is being used as a speaker.  Storage may or may not be on the phone.  If they had said "I listen to music from my phone", that would imply that it is stored on the phone.
But really you are asking about what the person meant.  That depends on that person.

Yes, they listen to music that is either stored on the phone, or streamed through the phone.  The actual technology isn't specified by the English, since the technology keeps changing.
Perhaps in the future the music will be generated by ai in real time, and won't be "stored" or "streamed" but you'd still say the same.
